# Authenticate to Azure AD Without Credentials

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

In normal Azure AD authentication we will authenticate to Azure AD using a valid AD username and password. But consider a situation,

In our current situation there is no user present. Instead of that we have only a physical device like (iPhone / Android) Phone present.

So my doubt is, without a valid username & password is it possible to authenticate to Azure AD by using a Device ID or IME Number.

In my use case, I am creating a retail mobile application in which a sales man and a shop present, for salesman we have a username and password. But for the shop the retail outlet, our client will give a physical device; So by using the ID or configuring it in Azure is it possible to bypass the login.

Comment: Um... it's not possible login AAD with device ID because Azure AD use Oauth to do authorization for Apps. Are you trying to make SSO for your App on the device?

Comment: We are trying to authenticate / trying to access resources by bypassing Azure AD login. In few scenarios we have only Physical device. The users of the Physical devices don't have AD credentials so trying for an alternative approach. Like authenticate using a registered device or something similar to that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So my doubt is, without a valid username & password is it possible to
>   authenticate to Azure AD by using a Device ID or IME Number.

No, it's not possible to achieve this.

**Why:**

For Native Application, Azure AD use OIDC/OAuth 2.0 for authorization and authentication. This also needs to user sign in AAD with their credentails:

[image]

**For your scenario:**

I understand what do you want to approach. But it's not possible. Although AAD is very powerful, but it cannot leave out User Identity. Even Intune is a device management service and can mange mobile devices, but it also needs to enroll devices with a user identity.

One method which can leave users sign in is Oauth client_credentials flow, but it's for service to service call. It's not for Native Application and even this flow cannot use device ID.

**So, what I suggest is :**

Though use Device ID to authentication is a easy way to do authorization, but AAD doesn't support this. If you feel it's trouble to let user login your app with user credentials, you can try to use [AAD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview). With AAD B2C, the user can use social account to sign-up and sign-in your application.

Hope this helps!

Comment: And the reason why you can't use client credentials is because the app is a public client app. The keys could be dumped by the user from the app.

Comment: @Wayne : What about self signed certificates in Azure AD, I read somewhere that using self signed certificate we can login to azure ad without username and password. Could you please share some insight on this. Some link or something like that.

Comment: @Stephan Ronald Is it possible ?

Comment: Hi,@StephanRonald  There is a [certificate credetials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials) without username and password, but it also need UI to choose one cert to authentication/authorization for Native App.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT : Can you suggest some samples / blogs that describes the  certificate credetials flow in mobile app

Comment: @StephanRonald . There is a Sample for [Authenticating to Azure AD in daemon apps with certificates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-certificate-credential/).